# Usage of onError attribute in Richfaces 4.5

Tags: richfaces, ajax4jsf, onerror

I want to make use of onerror attribute in Richfaces to handle exceptions for my ajax requests. For that i have used

```
<a4j:commandButton value="OK" 
actionListener="#{aBean.handler()}"
onerror="showNotification();">
```

and in my Managed bean :

```
ABean{
    public void handler(){
        throw new SomeException("Error to the browser");
    }
}
```

Though, i have thrown exception in my handler, my showNotification() is never called.

Can I handle my application level exceptions using onerror attribute? Any pointers or examples on this topic is much appreciated.

Comment: you meant `actionListener="#{aBean.handler}"` without `()`?

Comment: I dont see any difference in both the ways #{aBean.handler()} or #{aBean.handler}. Dont we?

Comment: Yes, it this case yes, but also look at the end of my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [docs](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_5_X/vdldoc/a4j/commandButton.html#onerror) you can read that `onerror` attribute works:

> when the request results in an error

This basically means that request must **ends with HTTP error**. For example HTTP 500, which can mean that server is not avaible at the moment.

Example of it (java):

```java
public void handler2() throws IOException {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    context.getExternalContext().responseSendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND,
            "404 Page not found!");
    context.responseComplete();
}
```

and `a4j:commandButton` (xhtml)

```html
<a4j:commandButton value="OK" actionListener="#{bean.handler2}" 
    onerror="console.log('HTTP error');" />
```

In JavaScript console you should see "HTTP error".

In any other case of exceptions `oncomplete` code will be fired, since AJAX request end with success. So if you wan't to react to the exception in your code you must handle it yourself. There are many ways to do this. I use this:

```java
public boolean isNoErrorsOccured() {
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    return ((facesContext.getMaximumSeverity() == null) || 
                (facesContext.getMaximumSeverity()
                    .compareTo(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO) <= 0));
}
```

And my `oncomplete` looks like this:

```html
<a4j:commandButton value="OK" execute="@this" actionListener="#{bean.handler1}"
    oncomplete="if (#{facesHelper.noErrorsOccured})
        { console.log('success'); } else { console.log('success and error') }" />
```

and with handler like this:

```java
public void handler1() {
    throw new RuntimeException("Error to the browser");
}
```

In JavaScript console you would see "success and error".

---

BTW. It's better to write `actionListener="#{bean.handler3}"` instead of `actionListener="#{bean.handler3()}"`. The reason behind it:

```java
public void handler3() { // will work
    throw new RuntimeException("Error to the browser");
}

// the "real" actionListener with ActionEvent won't work and
// method not found exception will be thrown
public void handler3(ActionEvent e) { 
    throw new RuntimeException("Error to the browser");
}
```

Comment: Thanks Emil. I just want to send the exception details message/data from handler method to the browser as part of error response. so that i can use it in onerror attribute like console.log(exceptionDetails); I used onerror="console(event.data)" but i see undefined in the console.

Comment: Glad I could help. But this is another question. If you like my answer to your _original_ question, please accept it. If you have different question, please ask it in different topic. (You can't use `event.data` like this if you haven't set it first.)